# How do I connect Mail.app to my local `mbox` account

Tags: mail.app, email, ventura, macos

I am on macOS Ventura.

I receive mail in my local `mbox` from `cron` jobs. I would like to view them, mark them as read/unread, and delete them through the GUI - ideally using the Mail.app.

Is this no longer supported? I remember being able to do it from the early days of OS X, and it was the default in Rhapsody.